# Tabindex is not working for the div element to open modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**I need help to fix below scenario.**

I have a div wrapped with a image. When I click with mouse on div section a small tooltip modal will be displayed to show the address. (imagine the example as having numbers on map, on clicking the numbers it will popup the address).

To have the same behavior with keyboard navigation, I have provided tabindex="0" for the div.

Now I am able to reach the div , but when I click by pressing enter / spacebar, I am not able to view the tooltip modal.

keydown events are also not working

Can anyone help me what could be the root cause. An example will be more easier to understand better

Comment: Could you post your javascript? It will be easier to see what is happening

Comment: `An example will be more easier to understand` Ya, for sure... So where is yours?

Answer (score 0):

because probably you're using a tooltip plugin which works with **click** events by default, but you also need [keyboards events](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/) to make it works with enter/spacebar.

Now, maybe that plugin supports them too, if you can tell us which one we'll find out ;)

Anyway a generic solution would be to

- attach a keyboard event to your div
- catch when user press enter/spacebar
- trigger a click

Try this code:

```
$('#target').on('keyup', function(e){
    //13 = Enter key, 31 == Spacebar key
    if(e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 32) $(this).click();
})
```

See this example: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bftod7yv/1/)